# NSJSONSerialization doesn't parse NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, json, ios7, nsjsonserialization

I need to generate JSON of the POST data and get an exception.

This is the dictionary with a "records" key, that contains an array of `NSManagedObjects`.

It seems it is throwing an exception when parsing it into json.

```
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[super requestData] options:0 error:&error];
```

[image]

It fails with the following exception.  Any idea why this is happening?

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (FTRecord)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01aae5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x018318b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01aae3bb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   Foundation                          0x015760f0 _writeJSONValue + 771
    4   Foundation                          0x0157a470 ___writeJSONArray_block_invoke + 129
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x01b2b05d __53-[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 61
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x01b2af92 -[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 258
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x01aa80a5 -[NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:] + 53
    8   Foundation                          0x0157a381 _writeJSONArray + 275
```

**FTRecord**:

```
@interface FTRecord : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic) BOOL isRealEntry;
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval timestamp;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * notes;
@property (nonatomic) double orderingValue;
@property (nonatomic) int16_t rating;
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval recordDate;

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs, NSManagedObject doesn't meet NSJSONSerialization's criteria for valid objects:

> An object that may be converted to JSON must have the following
>   properties:
>
> The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary. All objects are
>   instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull. All
>   dictionary keys are instances of NSString. Numbers are not NaN or
>   infinity.

You can test this by calling `isValidJSONObject:`